# Using IOptions for instance created using Activator in c#

Tags: c#, generics, activator

I'm looking for any pattern/factory to dynamic create instance of class and provide options for init.

So for example, i have `IParser` interface and some classes.

```cs
public interface IParser
{
    void Setup(IParserOptions options);
}

public class CsvParser: IParser
{
    public void Setup(IParserOptions options)
    {
    }
}

public class XlsParser: IParser
{
    public void Setup(IParserOptions options)
    {
    }
}
```

The same for `IParserOptions`.

```cs
public interface IParserOptions
{
}

public class CsvParserOptions: IParserOptions
{
    public string PropertySpecificToCsv { get; set; }
}

public class XlsParserOptions: IParserOptions
{
    public string PropertySpecificToXls { get; set; }
}
```

There is somewhere just basic instance creation using Activator. But it doesn't matter.

```cs
var parserType = GetType("xxx");
var parser = (IParser)Activator.CreateInstance(parserType);
```

Now I have parser and I need to call `Setup` and pass `IParserOptions` definition.
But I need to initialize and use `CsvParserOptions` or `XlsParserOptions` based on created parser type.

```cs
// if csv
var csvOptions = new CsvParserOptions { PropertySpecificToCsv = 'abc' };
parser.Setup(csvOptions);

// if xls
var xlsOptions = new XlsParserOptions { PropertySpecificToXls = 'abc' };
parser.Setup(xlsOptions);
```

How to achieve this? Is there any pattern?

Comment: Well, yeah. You mentioned it yourself, the **Factory** pattern: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern#C#

Comment: But I think it is not possible to achieve this with just one factory, right? I can have factory instead of activator to get IParser instance. But how to create IParserOptions based on created IParser type and init "data"?

Comment: The factory knows! That's the whole idea. Because it knows the type of the class, it knows the type of the parameters. I don't know enough about where you are getting the initialization data from. Perhaps adding more detail to the question? Also, how about passing the option class to the constructor instead of creating a temporal dependency with the `Setup` method?

Comment: Well I have no existing code. I'm just looking for solution how to implement dynamic creation of multiple parsers with different options. I don't want to use any `if-then-else` mechanism and still be able to get expected initialised instance of parser. Let's say there is some common service providing configuration data, but still it is just source. Every option will be initialised differently.

Comment: Then the factory would query the service and use the configuration data to instantiate the right type of class. What I have personally done in the past is to read information from the configuration file.